# How to open a folder in explorer view using a uri path in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm developing an extension, in which I want to prompt the user to select a folder in their file system and to open that folder in their explorer view. Currently I'm using `window.showOpenDialog` to open a filesystem dialog box, which returns a promise that resolves to an array of uris. **I'd like to open their selected path (stored under `returnUriArray[0].path`) in their explorer view. How can I do that?**

I've explored `commands.executeCommand("vscode.openFolder")` which I don't want to use unless I can manipulate it, because it refreshes the entire VSCode instance and removes anything previously open in the explorer view. So if the answer to my first question is to use the openFolder command (which I've seen in a lot of examples of other extensions that perform this task), can I manipulate it so that it doesn't remove all previously existing explorer folders? I can't easily find documentation for the openFolder command when used in the executeCommand function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`updateWorkspaceFolders()` might be what you're looking for? It can be used to add, delete or replace folders. The following would add `folderUriToAdd`:

```ts
vscode.workspace.updateWorkspaceFolders(0, 0, {uri: folderUriToAdd});
```